# Inequality for inverse M-matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Imagine that $A$ and $B$ are $N \times N$ M-matrices with $A < B$ (entrywise). I know that then $B^{-1} < A^{-1}$ (entrywise), but want to extend this inequality in the following way: $$\left(\mathrm{diag}\left(B^{-1}\iota\right)\right)^{-1} B^{-2} < \left(\mathrm{diag}\left(A^{-1}\iota\right)\right)^{-1} A^{-2},$$ (again entrywise) where $\iota$ is the $N \times 1$ vector of ones. Any tips would be appreciated.